How can I insert a button in the tab bar of my React Native app that does not navigate to any screen but instead triggers a custom function?
In my React Native application using Expo, I have a tab bar with multiple screens. I want to add a button in the middle of the tab bar that doesn't navigate to any screen but instead triggers a custom function when pressed. The goal is for this button to behave differently from the other tab buttons, which navigate to different screens.
I'm not sure how to add a button that doesn't perform navigation but still integrates with the tab bar. Specifically, I want to know how to:
Insert a custom button in the tab bar.
Prevent it from triggering any navigation.
Make it execute a custom function when pressed.
I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this in an Expo React Native app.
I tried positioning the button absolutely within the tab bar by using position: 'absolute' to place it in the center. However, this approach caused several issues. The button's absolute positioning affected the layout of the other tab bar buttons, causing them to shift or overlap. Additionally, the button wasn't very responsive to touch or press events, making it difficult for users to interact with it reliably. Despite adjusting the styles, I couldn't get the button to behave as expected without interfering with the rest of the tab bar layout.

You could possibly use the tabBar property from the "Tab Navigator" and take care of the Tab Bars implementation yourself.
Something like this:
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<NavigationParams>();

const tabs = [{ home: { screen: HomeScreen, name: 'Home' } }, ....];

...

  const renderTab = useCallback(
    (tabProps) => {
      return <MainTab {...tabProps} />;
    },
    [],
  );

return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="home"
      tabBar={renderTab}>
      {Object.entries(tabs).map(([, component]) => (
        <Tab.Screen
          name={component.name}
          component={component.screen}
          key={component.name}
        />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );


And in the MainTab component you take care of the custom onPress action (e.g. navigate to another page or trigger a custom function).
Let me know if I misunderstood something :)
